# Removing underscores from model classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4, .net-4.5, edmx

I have a database with tables that contain underscore in their name. I want to have them removed from the classes that are generated when I create a model. I was able to achieve it by customizing the t4 templates but the names should also be modified in the edmx file. Is there any way to customize the edmx generation?

Comment: How are you generating the EDMX?

Comment: @podiluska: They are generated by visual studio when I choose add new item and add tables from database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not (at least not an easy way) customize the process used to generate entities and names when using EDM generator. You can modify the tables' names via the wizard or, if feel with luck, add a MEF extension that post-processes the model but you must have to modify the [model's XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.entity.design.extensibility.imodelgenerationextension%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @Dai I forgot initially about the IModelGenerationExtension way! But then remeber :)

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you have to modify the EDMX (and other) files after they've been generated.

You can write an XML processor yourself to do this, or you can use a third-party VS add-in to do it for you. Personally I use Hugati DBML Tools: http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/

Comment: Yes, the product was recently updated. It supports VS2008, 2010 and 2012.